# Python Battery AI - How to log only if battery is connected or disconnected

Tags: python, battery

I'm making a Artificial Inteligence battery monitor look's like on iOS13 and i need to log the battery percentage/hour/plugged only when the user connect or disconnect the charger plug.

i tried to do something like:

```py
if str(plugged) == "True":
    log_file.write(current_info + "\r\n")
elif str(plugged) == "False"
      log_file.write(current_info + "\r\n")
```

but the script don't stop to loop on "True"

Here is the main function of my code

```
log_file = open("activity_log.txt", "w")

while True:
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
            # Check if charger is plugged in or not
    plugged = battery.power_plugged

            # Check for current battery percentage
    percent = str(battery.percent)

    # Check for the current system time
    sys_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    current_info = percent + " " + str(sys_time) + " " + str(plugged)

    if str(plugged) == "True":
        log_file.write(current_info + "\r\n")

log_file.close()
```

the project on github if you want to test or implement it: https://github.com/peterspbr/battery-ai

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  An off-site link is not acceptable.

Comment: You mention that the script doesn't 'stop to loop on "True"'.  You have written no loop; I'm confused how you think the program should loop.  Also, your two branches (`if` and `else`) do exactly the same thing, which makes your `if` useless.

Comment: I don't want the script loop, i want that script only works and write into the log file when the user connect or disconnect the plug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you want to exit the loop when variable `plugged` is True? Something to take into account is that Python is a string typing language, that means, that it is not the same "True" and True.

```
log_file = open("activity_log.txt", "w")
plugged = False
while not plugged:
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
            # Check if charger is plugged in or not
    plugged = battery.power_plugged

            # Check for current battery percentage
    percent = str(battery.percent)

    # Check for the current system time
    sys_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    current_info = percent + " " + str(sys_time) + " " + str(plugged)

    if str(plugged) == "True":
        log_file.write(current_info + "\r\n")

log_file.close()
```

PD: I am assuming variable `batery.power_plug` is a bool type.

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured out what you're trying to do: you want to log information when the battery plug changes status.  You're having trouble because you've done nothing to track whether or not the battery has been plugged in.  Try this:

```
was_plugged = battery.power_plugged
while True:
    ...
    if battery.power_plugged != was_plugged:
        log_file.write(current_info + "\r\n")
        was_plugged = battery.power_plugged
```

---

Please work through more tutorials on basic Python types.  It's hard to follow an indirect way of checking a value: you converted a Boolean to text, and then checked against the resulting string:

```
if str(plugged) == "True":
```

All you need is the direct Boolean test:

```
if plugged:
```

Comment: This is what i want! But i cannot remove `was_plugged` variable from `while` loop because it will not work.

Comment: `was_plugged` is a new variable; what prompts you to remove it from the loop?  "will not work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: I'm working with psutil library to monitoring battery status, so i need to create a variable `battery = psutil.sensors_battery()` inside the `while` loop because if i create this variable out of the loop, the script will run this only one time, and will stop to monitoring the battery information. If i had understood you, i should create another while loop to log when the battery plug is unplugged right?

Comment: No ... I only modified your existing code.  The ellipsis (the `...`) represents the remaining code.  All I want you to change is to replace your references to your variable `plugged` with the code I supplied.